# Coupon Label Does not Show if discount 0%

Tags: magento2, coupon

I want a way of adding a coupon code that is basically just an identifier for a promotion e.g. Free Gift Wrapping or a free product give away.

I do not want to go the route of having to have the customer add a product to the basket however and thought it would just be simpler to have a 0% coupon code. This applied however no label shows at checkout or within transaction emails.

The email order items seems to use the block Magento\Sales\Block\Order\Totals to check if there is a discount with below code:

```
    /**
     * Add discount
     */
    if ((double)$this->getSource()->getDiscountAmount()) {
        if ($this->getSource()->getDiscountDescription()) {
            $discountLabel = __('Discount (%1)', $source->getDiscountDescription());
        } else {
            $discountLabel = __('Discount');
        }
        $this->_totals['discount'] = new \Magento\Framework\DataObject(
            [
                'code' => 'discount',
                'field' => 'discount_amount',
                'value' => $source->getDiscountAmount(),
                'label' => $discountLabel,
            ]
        );
    }
```

So i want to change this to not check if 0 but to check if a coupon code was applied instead regardless of the discount.

How can I have these coupon labels show even if there is no discount?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Show 0 Value Discount Coupons on Transaction Emails

I used a preference for the `Magento\Sales\Block\Order\Total` class to override the `_initTotals()` function using **di.xml** within a module:

> Di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Sales\Block\Order\Totals" type="Harrigo\EverDiscountLabel\Block\Order\Totals" />
</config>
```

> New Method:

```
class Totals extends \Magento\Sales\Block\Order\Totals
{

    public function _initTotals() {
        $source = $this->getSource();

        $this->_totals = [];
        $this->_totals['subtotal'] = new \Magento\Framework\DataObject(
            ['code' => 'subtotal', 'value' => $source->getSubtotal(), 'label' => __('Subtotal')]
        );

        /**
         * Add shipping
         */
        if (!$source->getIsVirtual() && ((double)$source->getShippingAmount() || $source->getShippingDescription())) {
            $this->_totals['shipping'] = new \Magento\Framework\DataObject(
                [
                    'code' => 'shipping',
                    'field' => 'shipping_amount',
                    'value' => $this->getSource()->getShippingAmount(),
                    'label' => __('Shipping & Handling'),
                ]
            );
        }

        /**
         * Add discount
         */
        if ((double)$this->getSource()->getDiscountAmount() != 0 OR $this->getSource()->getDiscountDescription() != null) {
            if ($this->getSource()->getDiscountDescription()) {
                $discountLabel = __('Discount (%1)', $source->getDiscountDescription());
            } else {
                $discountLabel = __('Discount');
            }
            $this->_totals['discount'] = new \Magento\Framework\DataObject(
                [
                    'code' => 'discount',
                    'field' => 'discount_amount',
                    'value' => $source->getDiscountAmount(),
                    'label' => $discountLabel,
                ]
            );
        }

        $this->_totals['grand_total'] = new \Magento\Framework\DataObject(
            [
                'code' => 'grand_total',
                'field' => 'grand_total',
                'strong' => true,
                'value' => $source->getGrandTotal(),
                'label' => __('Grand Total'),
            ]
        );

        /**
         * Base grandtotal
         */
        if ($this->getOrder()->isCurrencyDifferent()) {
            $this->_totals['base_grandtotal'] = new \Magento\Framework\DataObject(
                [
                    'code' => 'base_grandtotal',
                    'value' => $this->getOrder()->formatBasePrice($source->getBaseGrandTotal()),
                    'label' => __('Grand Total to be Charged'),
                    'is_formated' => true,
                ]
            );
        }
        return $this;
        
    }
}
```

This works fine by just modifying the if statement to check if a description is available allowing label to show if there is a description / label for the coupon also. I would rather do this via a plugin however this is a protected method so will have to stick to a preference.

### Show 0 Value Discount Coupons on Checkout and Cart

The discount labels however still do not show for checkout or cart. Fixing this is simple enough using a mixin for `Magento_SalesRule/js/view/summary/discount` for checkout and `Magento_SalesRule/js/view/cart/totals/discount` for the cart to modify the `isDisplayed()` function.

> view/frontend/requirejs.js

```
var config = {
 config: {
    mixins: {
        'Magento_SalesRule/js/view/summary/discount': {
            'Harrigo_EverDiscountLabel/js/view/summary/discount-mixin': true
        },
        'Magento_SalesRule/js/view/cart/totals/discount': {
            'Harrigo_EverDiscountLabel/js/view/summary/discount-mixin': true
        }
    }
 }
};
```

> view/frontend/web/js/view/summary/discount-mixin.js

```
define(function () {
 'use strict';

 var mixin = {

    isDisplayed: function () {
            if  (this.getCouponLabel()) 
            {
                return true;
            }
            return this.isFullMode() && this.getPureValue() != 0;
    }
 };

 return function (target) {
     return target.extend(mixin);
 };
});
```

This will show the £0.00 in the sidebars of checkout and cart however the label is there just needs the below css to showup:

```
.opc-block-summary .discount.coupon, .cart-container  .discount.coupon{
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: I am using Magento 2.1.16. I tried the above preference. But it totally removes the Totals block from emails. However, if I edit core files. Everything works fine. But I don't want to edit core files as it is not recommended.

Comment: Hi, I am trying your code for "Show 0 Value Discount Coupons on Checkout and Cart". I am getting $0.00 discount but not getting discount label. As you said we have to add css to showup,could you please help where we can add above css.